# How do I get event signaled in RIO windows sockets?

Tags: sockets, winapi, winsock, low-latency

I have a RIO socket with event completion type. After I call RIOSend, the event is not signaled and the program is stopped at the last line of the listing below. Is it expected to be signaled at all? If yes, what might be wrong in my code?

```
HANDLE hEvent = WSACreateEvent();

RIO_NOTIFICATION_COMPLETION type;

type.Type = RIO_EVENT_COMPLETION;
type.Event.EventHandle = hEvent;
type.Event.NotifyReset = TRUE;

RIO_CQ queue = rio.RIOCreateCompletionQueue(queueSize, &type);

// create and register sndBuffer ...
rio.RIOSend(requestQueue, &sndBuffer, 1, 0, NULL);
WaitForSingleObject(hEvent, INFINITE);
```

Comment: I am not passing RIO_CQ to RIOSend. I am passing RIO_RQ to the function.

Comment: I managed to get send work. I call RIONotify right after it. Not sure if I'm really supposed to do it (documentation is not clear enough about it).

Moreover, hEvent stays signaled ("NotifyReset = TRUE" doesn't help), so I have to manually reset hEvent for subsequent socket request. Is it a bug or I'm doing smth wrong?

Comment: Call `RIONotify()` when you are ready to receive the first event. When it is signaled, call `RIODequeueCompletion()` to get the I/O result and then call `RIONotify()` again for the next event. That next call to `RIONotify()` should then reset the event.